# Draw shapes on scrollable JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw rectangles on fairly large images in order to get the pixel coordinates of objects within the image.  I am able to display the image and make it scrollable, or display the image and be able to draw rectangles on top of it....but not both.

It's obvious that I'm drawing the image on top of the canvas that I'm trying to draw the rectangles on, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it all coexist.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DrawRect extends JPanel {

    int x, y, x2, y2;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private JPanel canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel p = new DrawRect();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    DrawRect() {
        x = y = x2 = y2 = 0; //
        MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);

        try {
            this.image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://previews.123rf.com/images/victoroancea/victoroancea1201/victoroancea120100059/12055848-tv-color-test-pattern-test-card-for-pal-and-ntsc.jpg"));
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DrawRect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        this.canvas = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(canvas);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void setStartPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setEndPoint(int x, int y) {
        x2 = (x);
        y2 = (y);
    }

    public void drawRect(Graphics g, int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
        int px = Math.min(x,x2);
        int py = Math.min(y,y2);
        int pw=Math.abs(x-x2);
        int ph=Math.abs(y-y2);
        g.drawRect(px, py, pw, ph);
    }

    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            setStartPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            setEndPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            setEndPoint(e.getX(), e.getY());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        drawRect(g, x, y, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image-drawing JPanel must be the same JPanel that draws the rectangle and that has the MouseAdapter added to it. For instance:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawRect2 extends JPanel {
    public static final String IMG_PATH = "https://previews.123rf.com/images/victoroancea"
            + "/victoroancea1201/victoroancea120100059"
            + "/12055848-tv-color-test-pattern-test-card-for-pal-and-ntsc.jpg";
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    public DrawRect2(Image img) {
        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(img);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(drawingPanel);
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        drawingPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
        drawingPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Image img = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        DrawRect2 mainPanel = new DrawRect2(img);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawRect2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public DrawingPanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
        if (rectangle != null) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);
            g2.draw(rectangle);
            g2.dispose(); // since we created this object
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (img == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            int w = img.getWidth(this);
            int h = img.getHeight(this);
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }
    }

    public void setRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    private Point p1;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        p1 = e.getPoint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (p1 != null) {
            createRect(e);
        }
    }

    private void createRect(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p2 = e.getPoint();
        int x = Math.min(p1.x, p2.x);
        int y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
        int width = Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
        int height = Math.abs(p1.y - p2.y);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        ((DrawingPanel) e.getSource()).setRectangle(r);
        ((DrawingPanel) e.getSource()).repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (p1 != null) {
            createRect(e);
        }
        p1 = null;
    }
}
```

So in this paintComponent method, I draw both the image and the Rectangle, using Graphics2D XOR mode to help show the lines regardless of the background color:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private Rectangle rectangle;

    public DrawingPanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
        if (rectangle != null) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setXORMode(Color.WHITE);
            g2.draw(rectangle);
            g2.dispose(); // since we created this object
        }
    }
```

I also have this method:

```
public void setRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
    this.rectangle = rectangle;
}
```

To allow the MouseListener/Adapter to pass in the Rectangle into this JPanel.

```
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    ((DrawingPanel) e.getSource()).setRectangle(r);
    ((DrawingPanel) e.getSource()).repaint();
```

Comment: That was it, thanks so much.  I know I should spend more time on the Swing documentation but this is just a quick one-off tool to help me calculate custom coordinates faster.  Was having to do it blindly before so this is a massive improvement!